# Build a list of matched elements from an Array of Objects with jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays, javascript-objects, each

I got a pretty simple code, but I bet it's really bad written.
I tried to create some objects inside an array, and then build a `list` using jQuery `.each()` method.

I think this is stupidly easy, but I'm just learning...

This is the jQuery code I've written:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //items
    var armas = {
        BK: {
            mano_izq: [{
                type: 2,
                index: 5,
                name: "juan"
            }, {
                type: 2,
                index: 5,
                name: "juancho"
            }]
        },
        MG: {
            mano_der: [{
                type: 2,
                index: 5,
                name: "juan2"
            }, {
                type: 2,
                index: 5,
                name: "juan3"
            }]
        }
    };

    //controles
    $("#selec").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".itemlist").each(armas.BK.mano_izq, function (i, value) {
            $(this).append('<li>'+ value.name +'</li>');
        });
    });
});
```

As you can see, in that example I'm trying to build this list (without success, sadly)

```
<ul class="itemlist">
    <li>juan</li>
    <li>juancho</li>
    <li>juan2</li>
    <li>juan3</li>
</ul>
```

You can check my fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Frondor/xbcxy8ur/

Answer (score 1):

You should iterate through your objects, not through the list.

```
$("#selec").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $itemlist = $(".itemlist");
    $.each(armas.BK.mano_izq, addLi);
    $.each(armas.MG.mano_der, addLi);
    function addLi(i, elem){
        $itemlist.append('<li>'+ elem.name +'</li>');
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ly8yfy5s/)

Comment: I preffer to use the `$.map()` method over this, but +1 for the _caching_ the `addLi` function

Comment: Well, actually `$.map()` has another intention. This method designed to translate one array to another one, not just to iterate through it even though translation _include_ iteration. But if you wanna write more obvious (== better maintainable) code use API methods for its intended purpose. Unfortunately with jQuery `$.map()` is really more handy then `$.each()` due to flaw in `$.each()` design (iterator as first argument) but in other "swiss-knife" libraries (such as underscore) `each` definitely better.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's `.each()` iterates over jQuery-objects. For regular objects, you'll need to use [$.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/), which can iterate over any collection.

```
$("#selec").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.each(armas.BK.mano_izq, function (i, value) {
        $('.itemlist').append('<li>'+ value.name +'</li>');
    });
    $.each(armas.MG.mano_der, function (i, value) {
        $('.itemlist').append('<li>'+ value.name +'</li>');
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you tell me what's the difference between `jQuery-objects` and regular ones? Is there any difference on syntax?

Comment: jQuery-objects are `DOM`-elements (such as divs, paragraphs, headers etc.) wrapped in a jQuery container, which includes all the jQuery-methods (such as `.each(), .html(), .append()`...). You can read more about them here: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$.map` to normalize your data, like this

```
var data = $.map(Object.keys(armas), function (el) {
   return $.map(Object.keys(armas[el]), function (key) {
       return armas[el][key];  
   });
});

$("#selec").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var list = $.map(data, function (el) {
        return '<li>' + el.name + '</li>';
    });

    // only once dom operation 
    $('.itemlist').html(list);
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/xbcxy8ur/2/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(armas.BK.mano_izq, function (i, value) {
   $(".itemlist").append('<li>'+ value.name +'</li>');
});

$.each(armas.MG.mano_der, function (i, value) {
        $(".itemlist").append('<li>'+ value.name +'</li>');
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xbcxy8ur/1/)**